# The Miller-Rabin Primality Test in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, recursion, primes, clojure

I am new to clojure and I wanted to test out my skills by taking an [existing implementation](https://jeremykun.com/2013/06/16/miller-rabin-primality-test/) written in Python and writing it in Clojure.

**Concerns**

My main concerns are where I use `cond` and put an `upto` parameter in the function definitions of `isWitness` and `probablyPrime`. I am not sure if that's the best way to loop (I tried using the actual `loop` construct but found out, you couldn't break out of it).

Furthermore, on line 41 where I call the `isWitness` function from `probablyPrime` seems very messy. I am calling `decompose` twice when calling it once would be best (I don't know how to simulate local "variables" or use `let` properly).

Also I have separated a part of my `isWitness` into another function called `checkWitness`. I am not sure if that's the best way to do it.

```
(ns jeremy-kun.miller-rabin
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

;; This is the clojure version of the original python code done on jeremykun website
;; https://jeremykun.com/2013/06/16/miller-rabin-primality-test/
(defn pow [x y & [z]]
  (if z
    (mod (math/expt x y) z)
    (math/expt x y)))

(defn rand-between [n]
  (rand-nth (range 2 n)))

(defn decompose [exponent-of-two n]
  (if (not= 0 (mod n 2))
    {:exponent exponent-of-two :n n}
    (decompose (+ 1 exponent-of-two) (/ n 2))))

(defn checkWitness [possibleWitness p exponent remainder upto]
  (cond (> upto exponent) true
    (= (- p 1) (pow possibleWitness 2 p)) false
    :else (checkWitness (pow possibleWitness 2 p) p exponent remainder (inc upto)))
  )

(defn isWitness [possibleWitness p exponent remainder upto]
  (cond
    (or (= (pow possibleWitness remainder p) 1) (= (pow possibleWitness remainder p) (- p 1))) false
    (zero? exponent) true
    :else (checkWitness (pow possibleWitness remainder p) p exponent remainder upto)))


(defn probablyPrime [p accuracy upto]
  (if (or (= p 2) (= p 3))
    true)

  (if (< p 2)
    false)

  (cond
    (> upto accuracy) true
    (isWitness (rand-between (- p 2)) p (:exponent (decompose 0 (- p 1))) (:n (decompose 0 (- p 1))) 0) false
    :else (probablyPrime p accuracy (inc upto))
    ))

;;(def test-witness [[10 5] [11 9] [12 5] [13 10] [14 11] [15 3] [16 13] [17 3] [18 7] [19 11]])

;; 
;(prn
;  (map (fn [x] (isWitness (last x) (first x)
;                         (:exponent (decompose 0 (- (first x) 1))) (:n (decompose 0 (- (first x) 1)))
;                         0))
;       test-witness))

(prn (probablyPrime 25 100 0))                              ;; false
(prn (probablyPrime 100 100 0))                             ;; false
(prn (probablyPrime 151 100 0))                             ;; true
(prn (probablyPrime 97 100 0))                              ;; true
```

**Test Cases**

I have already included four test cases for primes. If you want to test more then just replace the first parameter and leave the rest as is, especially `upto`.

The block of code that is commented out tests the `isWitness` function. You can test it out by uncommenting the code and the value `test-witness`. The value `test-witness` is a list of lists. Each element in the list of list is the value to check and a random number between 2 and the value you want to test for primality minus 2.

For instance, `[10 5]`, 10 is the value to check for primality and `5` is a random number between 2 and 10.

If you uncomment the block and run the code, it should return

`(true false true false true true true false true false)`

which is what the python code runs if you use the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the translation of the `probablyPrime` function. In Clojure, a [function body](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#fn.) is an implicit [`do` form](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#do). The two `if` forms and  the `cond` form:

```
(defn probablyPrime [p accuracy upto]
  (if...
    )

  (if ...
    )

  (cond
    ...
    ))
```

... will be evaluated in succession. The values of the `(if ...)`s will be discarded; the result of the `(cond ...)` will be returned. The Python *returns* the associated value if either `if` condition is satisfied.

For example, the Clojure gives

```
(probablyPrime -2 0 1)
;true
```

... whereas the Python returns `false`.

I suggest you bring all the conditions under the `cond`:

```
(defn probablyPrime [p accuracy upto]
  (cond
    (or (= p 2) (= p 3)) true
    (< p 2) false
    (> upto accuracy) true
    (isWitness (rand-between (- p 2)) p (:exponent (decompose 0 (- p 1))) (:n (decompose 0 (- p 1))) 0) false
    :else (probablyPrime p accuracy (inc upto))))
```

---

There are other problems that make your Clojure unworkable for testing large numbers:

- You use proper recursion to express Python `for` loops. This may
  cause stack overflow and will certainly slow things down. Use
  Clojure's `recur` instead.
- Your `rand-between` function is [\$\mathcal{\Theta}(n)\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). This is a performance
  disaster when \$n\$ is huge.

---

There are also some constructions that would improve your code in small ways:

- Use `let` forms to avoid recalculating expressions.
- Use `inc` and `dec` instead of `(+ ... 1)` and `(- ... 1)`.
- Prefer explicit arities to rest parameters in function `pow`.

With these improvements, the rest of the code now looks as follows:

```
(ns miller-rabin.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

(defn pow
  ([x y] (math/expt x y))
  ([x y z] (mod (pow x y) z)))

(defn rand-between [n]
  (+ (rand-int (- n 2)) 2))

(defn decompose [exponent-of-two n]
  (if (odd? n)
    {:exponent exponent-of-two :n n}
    (recur (inc exponent-of-two) (quot n 2))))

(defn checkWitness [possibleWitness p exponent remainder upto]
  (let [possibleWitness (pow possibleWitness 2 p)]
    (or
     (> upto exponent)
     (and
       (not= (dec p) possibleWitness)
       (recur possibleWitness p exponent remainder (inc upto))))))

(defn isWitness [possibleWitness p exponent remainder upto]
  (let [possibleWitness (pow possibleWitness remainder p)]
    (cond
     (or (= possibleWitness 1) (= possibleWitness (dec p))) false
     (zero? exponent) true
     :else (checkWitness possibleWitness p exponent remainder upto))))
```

---

I've noticed that, in translation, several functions have acquired an extra argument that is used internally to control repetition. I'll just restore `decompose`:

```
(defn decompose [n]
  (loop [exponent-of-two 0, n n]
    (if (odd? n)
      {:exponent exponent-of-two :n n}
      (recur (inc exponent-of-two) (quot n 2)))))
```

The others - `isWitness` and `probablyPrime`  - are up to you. If you follow the Python, you don't need to factor out `checkWitness`.

---

To do:

- I have not seriously tested the above.
- Factoring out `checkWitness` from `isWitness` can be bettered using
  the [sequence library](http://clojure.org/reference/sequences#_the_seq_library).

Comment: @ferada Thanks. I would prefer big theta to big O. Is this possible.

Comment: Sure, it's just LaTeX markup, take a look at the source code now.

Comment: @ferada Thanks. I've used MathJax in the Mathematics site - didn't know it was available here.

Comment: Just a quick question for: `[exponent-of-two 0, n n]` does the `exponent-of-two 0,` set the value of `exponent-of-two` to 0?

Comment: @JeelShah Yes. In the approved lingo, it binds the local identifier `exponent-of-two` to the value `0`. And it binds thee local identifier `n` to the *global* value `n`, which is got from the argument.